# Get Value from <ion-input> in function using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, input, ionic4, v-model

Can someone tell how I can get the Value of an Input field in an Ionic Vue Application.
I've tried the following way, but I get an error saying "this.inputEAN is not defined". Can someone tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance:

```
<ion-input v-model="inputEAN" placeholder="f.e. 12345678910" clearInput="true" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="13" required="true"></ion-input>
```

With:

```
components: { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonContent, IonPage},
methods: {
  addProduct: function(){
    console.log(this.inputEAN);
    //alert(this.inputEAN);
  },
},
data(){
  return{
  inputEAN: ''
  };
},
setup() {
  return { i: allIcons };
},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The ionic-vue uses Vue3 which makes use of composition API, a concept introduced in vue3.

Composition API makes use of `setup()` function to make variable accessible to the template part of the application, so when using Vue3 your `data()` will get converted to something like:

```
setup(){
  const inputEAN = reactive({ inputEAN: '' });
  return {
    inputEAN
  };
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I implement you logic, I still can not use the variable with "this.inputEAN". How do I use the Variable in a custom method like it is defined in my example.

Comment: you don't have to use composition API with ionic...

Answer (score 0):

you need to import and add as a component `IonInput`

```
components: { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonContent, IonPage, IonInput},
methods: {
  addProduct: function(){
    console.log(this.inputEAN);
    //alert(this.inputEAN);
  },
},
data(){
  return {
    inputEAN: ''
  };
},
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the "IonInput" but still can't access the variable via "this.inputEAN". Do you have another idea, where the problem could come from?

Comment: what i suggested works, so there must be an error somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this, just use inputEAN.value .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30629480)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue's [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to do this. So add a ref to your element:

```
<ion-input ref="inputElement"></ion-input>
```

And then grab it in your setup:

```
setup() {
    const inputElement = ref();
    return { inputElement };
}
```

Then you can just access it like a normal DOM element:

```
console.log(inputElement.value.$el.value);
```